# When to use ~'some-symbol in Clojure Macro?

Tags: clojure, macros, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

When I was reading The Joy of Clojure I came across some code.

```clj
(fn [~'key ~'r old# new#]
                  (println old# " -> " new#)
```

What is the exact behaviour of this declaration `~'some-symbol`.

Differences between `some-symbol#` and `'~another-symbol` or gensym?

**The Joy Of Clojure:** (Did not understand)

> You’ll see the pattern `~'symbol` at times in Clojure
> macros for selectively capturing a symbolic name in the body of a
> macro. The reason for this bit of awkwardness[11] is that Clojure’s
> syntax-quote attempts to resolve symbols in the current context,
> resulting in fully qualified symbols. Therefore, `~'` avoids that
> resolution by unquoting a quote.

Comment: P.S.  While I like "The Joy of Clojure", it is a somewhat advanced book and you may wish to re-read it after reading 2-4 other beginning/intermediate books. It was the very first Clojure book I read and many of the topics were difficult to understand without enough background knowledge in Clojure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see an example in the Tupelo library with [the Literate Threading Macro](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#literate-threading-macro).  We want the user to type the symbol `it` and have it recognized by the macro.  Here's the definition:

```clj
(defmacro it->
  "A threading macro like as-> that always uses the symbol 'it' 
   as the placeholder for the next threaded value "
  [expr & forms]
  `(let [~'it ~expr
         ~@(interleave (repeat 'it) forms)
         ]
     ~'it))
```

This is also referred to as an "anaphoric" macro.  The user then creates code like this:

```clj
(it-> 1
      (inc it)                                  ; thread-first or thread-last
      (+ it 3)                                  ; thread-first
      (/ 10 it)                                 ; thread-last
      (str "We need to order " it " items." )   ; middle of 3 arguments
;=> "We need to order 2 items." )
```

The user includes the special symbol `it` in their code, which the macro is expecting (& is required in this case).

This is a bit of a special case.  In most cases, you want the macro to work no matter what symbols the user picks. That is why most macros use `(gensym...)` or the reader version with "#" suffix like this example:

```clj
(defmacro with-exception-default
  "Evaluates body & returns its result.  In the event of an exception, default-val is returned
   instead of the exception."
  [default-val & body]
  `(try
     ~@body
     (catch Exception e# ~default-val)))
```

This is the "normal" case, where the macro creates a "local variable" `e#` that is guaranteed not to overlap with any user symbol. A similar example shows the `spyx` macro creating a "local variable" named `spy-val#` to temporarily hold the result of evaluating the expression `expr`:

```clj
(defmacro spyx
  "An expression (println ...) for use in threading forms (& elsewhere). Evaluates the supplied
   expression, printing both the expression and its value to stdout, then returns the value."
  [expr]
  `(let [spy-val# ~expr]
     (println (str (spy-indent-spaces) '~expr " => " (pr-str spy-val#)))
     spy-val#))
```

Note that for the `(println...)` statement, we see the opposite syntax of `'~expr` -- but that is a topic for another day.